# Изменение tagName с запуском последующих функций

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте!

Написал функцию, которая изменяет `tagName` элемента. Всё работает отлично, но не задача! Все остальные функции, которые идут после этой, не работают. А если указать до функции замены `tagName`, то всё хорошо.

В общем, код с проблемой:

```js
function tagName(elem, tagName) {
  $(elem).replaceWith(elem.outerHTML.replace(/^\<[^ ]+(.*)\<\/[^ ]+\>$/, '<'+tagName+'$1</'+tagName+'>'));
};

$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.block', function() {
    tagName(this, 'span');
    $(this).css('background', 'black'); // А это где? Фон остался белым!
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
div.block {border: 2px solid red}
span.block {border: 2px solid blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block"></div>
```

Может кто знает способ получше, как заменить `tagName` без этой "ошибки"? Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Внутри `tagName` элемент `elem` удаляется из DOM-a. `$(this).css('background' ...` - воздействует на элемент, который находится уже вне документа.

Comment: @Igor, это понятно. Я не могу придумать, как можно исправить это. Смотрел на SO, все пишут типичные варианты замены, где есть эта же "проблема"

Comment: @Yuri, ты вставил новый элемент, а стиль применяешь к старому. То есть все работает именно так, как и ожидалось. Для решения просто _возвращай_ новый элемент из `tagName` и применяй дальнейшие стили уже к нему

Comment: @Grundy, хотелось бы, что бы дальнейшие запускались по тому же `this`

Comment: @Yuri, это невозможно.

Comment: @Grundy, уже понял. Добавьте свой комментарий в качестве ответа и я его засчитаю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае функция не *меняет* tagName, а удаляет старый элемент и добавляет *новый*. Таким образом в разметке уже не старый элемент, на который ссылается `this`, а новый созданный, поэтому последующее применение к `this`

```
$(this).css('background', 'black');
```

Не приносит результат.

Это поведение изменить невозможно, так как, невозможно изменить значение на которое будет ссылаться *this* внутри функции.

В качестве обходного пути, стиль должен применяться к новому созданному элементу, для этого его нужно вернуть из функции `tagName`

Пример:

```js
function tagName(elem, tagName) {
  var el = $(elem.outerHTML.replace(/^\<[^ ]+(.*)\<\/[^ ]+\>$/, '<' + tagName + '$1</' + tagName + '>'));
  $(elem).replaceWith(el);
  return el;
};

$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.block', function() {
    tagName(this, 'span')
      .css('background', 'black'); // А это где? Фон остался белым!
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
div.block {
  border: 2px solid red
}
span.block {
  border: 2px solid blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Очень жаль, что `this` это навсегда :)

Comment: @Yuri, наоборот хорошо, тут еще не все с потерей контекста разобрались, а ты хочешь самому в неизвестной функции его менять :)

Comment: Но лично моя бы функция выглядела куда симпатичнее ))

Comment: @Yuri, как например?

Comment: Если бы не надо было создавать дополнительную переменную. А то так не очень удобно, как по мне

Comment: @Yuri, без нее не получится, потому что `replaceWith` возвращает _удаленный_ элемент, и ссылки на созданный элемент не остается